# SettingWithCopyWarning on slice obtained by groupby.get_group

Tags: pandas, group-by, slice

Is there a way to determine if the DataFrame is a slice of some other object to handle case of SettingWithCopyWarning?

I finally was able to reproduce example of SettingWithCopyWarning for the case where I am doing computations: df['new_col'] = value.

The issue was that the df is itself a slice return from grpBY.get_group().  This was tough to assess since adding columns is something done a LOT in the computations.

So now that I understand that the df is itself a slice of a bigger dataframe I understand the warning but debugging it was very difficult as one had to understand that the DF passed to my service function is a slice.   Here is the example: 
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns = ['col'+str(i) for i in range(5)])
df['grpID'] = df.apply(lambda x : df.columns[np.random.randint(5)], axis=1)
gBY = df.groupby('grpID')

def WorkOnDataFrameGroupSlice(gDF):
    gDF['new_col'] = gDF.col1/gDF.col3
    print gDF

for g in gBY.groups.keys():
    gDF = gBY.get_group(g)
    WorkOnDataFrameGroupSlice(gDF)
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> WorkOnDataFrameGroupSlice(gBY)
__main__:4: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
      col0      col1      col2      col3      col4 grpID   new_col
1  0.30118  0.649366 -2.004724 -0.102476 -0.312678  col4 -6.336769
       col0      col1      col2      col3      col4 grpID  new_col
2 -0.344893  0.579363 -0.556483 -0.383786 -2.312829  col2  -1.5096
       col0      col1      col2      col3      col4 grpID    new_col
0 -0.916921 -0.329640 -0.959094 -0.667048  0.902691  col3   0.494177
3  1.936567  1.082553 -1.059511 -0.102200  0.902362  col3 -10.592540
4  0.808047  0.737737  0.380464  0.048980  0.674635  col3  15.061955
```